# Scoping issues in my C# class

Tags: c#, algorithm, oop, data-structures

I have a class like

```
public class DiceOnYacht
{
     private static byte numdie = 5;

     // ... 

     private bool isSmallStraight ( byte [numdie] die )
     {
          // ... 
     }
}
```

and the compiler isn't liking methods whose signatures use `numdie`, e.g. the method `isSmallStraight` above. To those it says

> error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `numdie', expecting`,' or `]'

Additionally, for some strange reason, it has problems with the lines denoted in the following

```
public byte getAnyScore ( Category cat, byte [numdie] die )
{
    byte score; 
    switch (cat)
    {
        case Category.Ones: 
        case Category.Twos:
        case Category.Threes:
        case Category.Fours:
        case Category.Fives:
        case Category.Sixes:
        case Category.Sevens:
        case Category.Eights:
            score = getSinglesScores(cat,die); 
            break;
        case Category.SmallStraight
            score = isSmallStraight(die) ? 30 : 0; // this line
            break;
        case Category.AllDifferent
            score = die.Distinct().Count() == 5 ? 40 : 0; // and this line
            break;
        case Category.AllSame
            score = die.Distinct.Count() == 1 ? 50 : 0; // and this line
            break;
    }
    return score;
}
```

because it says

> Unexpected symbol `score'

I cannot think of any logical basis for these errors. Any guidance?

You can see this all [here](https://ideone.com/pF8vPO)

Comment: numdie is not a type, just a variable name, so i dont think you can use it quite like that, though i would ask someone confirm to be certain. And second error is you need ':' after each case, which you dont past Category.Eight

Comment: What `byte[numdie]die` supposed to do. Is it byte array? You have to assign its size inside method

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I can't enforce the size of the array in the method's signature?

Comment: Nope. Inside method do `byte[] die= new byte[numdie];`

Comment: @CarlyFiorina no, you can add any constraints to the method signature. One of ways is to add custom attribute to the parameter and check it at the runtime f.e. Or do just a simple if and throw `ArgumentException` when it is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the array can not be used in the parameter.

```
private bool isSmallStraight ( byte [] die )
{
     //use die  
}
```

There are methods on an array to find its dimentions.

```
die.Length
```

is pretty useful.

More info on using arrays in C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The size of the byte array should not be mentioned in the parameter.  It should be done as below.

```
byte[] b = new byte[numdie];
isSmallStraight(b);   // Calling method 'isSmallStraight'

//...

private bool isSmallStraight ( byte [] die )
{

}
```

Comment: passing a parameter and then overwriting it. There is no point in passing a parameter at all.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the user to pass in an array of type `byte` and a length of `numdie`. But you cannot do that in a parameter. You can only specify an array's length when you construct the array, not when you declare it. You can do this:

```
byte[] array = new byte[numdie];
```

But not this:

```
byte[numdie] array;
```

There is a work aroud for this: you can check the length of the array in the method. So your method is like this:

```
private bool isSmallStraight (byte[] die)
{ 
    if (die.Length != numdie) {
        throw new ArgumentException ("The length of die is not equal to numdie");
    // ... 
}
```

If it is not the right length, throw an exception!